# WP REST API Post Status Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest-api

I am getting my hands dirty in WP REST API. I have gone through a couple of tutorials and have a question using JavaScript to create a new post.

In [this](https://apppresser.com/wp-api-post-submission/) tutorial, the post `var status = 'draft';` (see code). **So I am just worried that won't anyone able to hack that status?**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    $( '#post-submission-form' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $( '#post-submission-title' ).val();
        var excerpt = $( '#post-submission-excerpt' ).val();
        var content = $( '#post-submission-content' ).val();
        var status = 'draft'; // this code

        var data = {
            title: title,
            excerpt: excerpt,
            content: content
        };

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wp/v2/posts',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
            },
            fail : function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
            }

        });

    });

} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this tutorial, the post var status = 'draft'; (see code). So I am just worried that won't anyone able to hack that status?

It depends who it is. A logged out user cannot create any posts at all. A subscriber cannot either. A contributor could create the post, but not publish it. An author or editor role however can change it to publish.

---

So, lets say that the user is logged in, and has a role that lets them publish posts, and they are on that page, and you're concerned that they might change `status = "draft"` to `status = "publish"`.

### First, the bug in your code

Firstly, the `status` variable is never used due to a bug in your code. The posts get created as `draft` posts not because you said so, but because that's the default status.

To fix this bug, you need to add this to `data`:

```
status: status
```

Until you do that, they could change `status` to `"banana"` and it wouldn't do anything.

### Second, REST is stateless

The REST API doesn't know what page the user is on, that's not how REST API's work. What they can and can't do is controlled via capabilities.

So who cares if they can modify your variable when they can just poke the API themselves?

They could copy paste the following code into their browsers dev tools console:

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wp/v2/posts',
        data: {
            title: "hello world",
            content: "post content",
            status: "publish"
        },
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
        },
    });
```

And hey presto, they don't need to modify your code! They have their own. As I said earlier, REST API requires 3 things:

- a nonce
- a cookie
- the required capabilities to do what's being asked.

Nothing requires them to use the code from your theme, or for your code to even load. As long as they're logged in, and they have the capability, it will allow them.

#### Who Can Change a Posts Status in The REST API?

Which is the crux of your question, and the answer is **it depends**. Anybody who tells you either yes or no is a liar, and has not thought it through.

For example, a `contributor` cannot publish a post, so if they changed the `post_status` to `publish` the API would reject the request. You'd receive a JSON structure telling you that what you tried was forbidden, and a 403 forbidden HTTP response code.

If a `subscriber` user tried, it would reject it too, even if the status was `draft`, because subscribers cannot create posts. You'd receive a JSON structure telling you that what you tried was forbidden, and a 403 forbidden HTTP response code.

If an `administrator` tried it, it would work, because `administrator` roles can do anything. You'd get a 200 http code success response. The same of an `editor` of `author`, because those roles can do that, as demonstrated by them being able to go to `wp-admin` and click the publish button.

This is because those roles have the capability to publish posts assigned to their roles. If you removed that capability then they would no longer be able to publish in the REST API, or the WP Admin interface

So as you see, **It depends on the roles and capabilities of the logged in user making the request**

Comment: Greatly explain. Thanks a lot. but what about `status` if anyone is logged in and have created post permission, will they be able to alter `status` from `draft` to `publish`?  I sorry if it is a silly question but just want to clear my understanding and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes and no, it's not that simple. If the current logged in users `role` has the `capability` to modify a posts status from `draft` to something else, then they can do that with the REST API. The same is true of XMLRPC, the post edit screen in their browser etc. This is the difference between hiding UI, and removing the ability to do something. If the user can go into the edit post screen and change the status from `draft` to `publish` in the publish post box, then they can do it in the REST API too. As for the JS variable `status` in your post, it's irrelevant. It isn't even being used

Comment: @pixelngrain I've expanded my post, as I mentioned, it looks like you're wanting a yes or a no answer. Such an answer is not possible, because it depends

Comment: Okay cool. I understood. I appreciate your time and effort to clear my doubts.